# When piping to a command via tee, output of first command is lost

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

The following command displays output of only grep command.

```
df|tee >(head -1) |grep -i '/dev'
```

whereas the following command gives output of both grep and head command

```
df|tee >(head -1) >(grep -i '/dev') >/dev/null
```

For the first command, why the output of head command is lost.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get both the header line and grep output, with GNU coreutils 8.31 (and 8.25 as well). Which version of tee and head are you using?

Comment: Second command is really temperamental for me for some reason, hangs most of the time but other times returns both the head and grep output instantly, is there some kind of race condition going on?

Comment: i am using GNU coreutils 8.28 on ubuntu

Comment: what were you expecting? in the 1st command, the pipe to grep is the stdout of both the tee and the head command. Another example `: | tee >(echo yup) | grep yup`

Comment: `tee` is an odd bob, since `: | tee >(echo yup) > /dev/null | grep -n yup` still prints `1:yup` when usually you might expect that after `> /dev/null`, there is nothing left to grep as is the case with `echo yup > /dev/null | grep yup`. Also when running `tee` in a shell, the shell prompt can appear in the middle of the output, too.

Comment: @frostschutz nothing to do with tee. replace it with true or : and obtain the same effect. The problem is that the process substitution (like all the other substitutions -- parameter, command, etc) is performed BEFORE any redirections.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.

Comment: @UncleBilly yes you are right. I was expecting that tee will only supply output of 'df' command to grep and also output of head command gets printed directly to stdout . I was not expecting output of tee and head command combine and going through pipe to grep.